# Custom autocomplete arrow control

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-events

I am trying to make custom autocomplete  input (I know about jQuery UI autocomplete, but I decided to write a simple one). Everything went fine, I did all the 'general' stuff - sending data to some PHP script, receiving suggestions. Then I enabled choosing an element on a mouse click, and also did some navigation using <kbd>down arrow</kbd>, <kbd>up arrow</kbd>  and <kbd>enter</kbd> keys. But I got stuck with an ambition to enable 'holding down\up arrow key' navigation (flicking through). A handler on my input listens for `keyup` event, and I perfectly understand that all I want is `keypress` event, because it maintains key hold. But `keypress` only works for printable characters which doesn't include down arrow\up arrow. So the question is: how can I make it work without `keypress`, or can I somehow override this event's maintained keys?

Thanks everybody, I've found the solution. Although `keypress` is meant to be fired only on printable characters, latest Opera and Firefox 5 do support it. But Chrome (and probably Safari, as they are quite similar) doesn't, whereas `keydown` gives the result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no way to overcome the `keypress` difficulty try something like this.  This is pseudocode I didn't do all the keycode detection.

```
var keyStop
onkeydown = function(){
  keyStop = setInterval(function(){scrollDown()},250);
}
onkeyup = function(){
  clearInterval(keyStop);
}
```

Comment: second function should be onkeyup?

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason got stuck in your development, I would recommend [Better Autocomplete](https://github.com/betamos/Better-Autocomplete), which is a lightweight jQuery plugin which is easy to customize.